# Php Two Combo box in a form control each other. How?

Tags: php

On php page in a form, One combo box has list of my Customer from mysql table customer. Another combo box has invoiceno stored in invoice table which has respective customer records. I want to select customer from first combo box and filter invoiceno from the second one according to the customer. Any one help me for php or java or Jquery or both codeings? Means if I select customer1 then in the second combo box should show all invoiceno respective to the custermer1.  No Refresh or ReLoad or Post form Pl. If I get the first selection in a php variable format example $customer,  it is enough for me. Thanks for any one help me.

Comment: Have you tried applying some AJAX to the problem?

Comment: @deceze: He, probably, doesn't want any further requests.

Comment: @Thrustmaster - He says "combo box has invoiceno stored in invoice table", I assume he's talking about a db table.

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to POST to the script. You dont want to invoke any server side activity. And you want to get the value user selects into a PHP variable. From what I understand, this means, you dont clearly get where PHP plays a role. The way you want it, you might want to use XAJAX : http://www.xajax-project.org But even this causes various REQUESTs to the PHP script internally.

I would suggest the below:

- Do a natural join in the SQL query.
- For a customer C1, there might be 100 Invoice numbers I1. The result of the query may be outputted in a JSON format. Something like this:

  `"RESULT" : [
      "C1" : ["I1", "I2", I3"],
      "C2" : ["I11", "I22", I33"]
  ]`
- **ALL** the data will be sent to the browser. This data can be stored as a Javascript Object. `Use JSON.parse("<PHP response here>");`
- Whenever the users selection changes in a combo box, have a function in Javascript to load the corresponding values in the second list.

**EDIT**: In case, you are dealing with a larger database, and you expect a larger dataset, I would HIGHLY recommend XAJAX -- Simple and easy! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is given, i think one is only restricted to pushing you in the right direction.  In a case where you there a large number of customers, it most likely be that you are working with a database, thus the following process:

- The Page of the selects is where you will need to make an [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) request on change of the select element.
- Using your JavaScript of your favorite [JavaScript library](http://speckyboy.com/2008/04/01/top-10-javascript-frameworks-which-do-you-prefer/) you'll make the request passing a value that you'll query your database for.
- Ofcourse you'll need to configure your PHP for GET or POST depending of you AJAX request, then query the database.
- Format the databases output to be a valid HTML of your selected element.
- Earlier you'll have configured your AJAX script to populate the proper element once the request has been successful.

Comment: He doesn't want further requests. :)

Answer (score 0):

If AJAX is not an option, you must load all the things (include customer & invoice), then you can use pure javascript/css to do that. It's a dirty work around, but it works.

First, let says that you have n customer, so you will have 1 combo box to select the customer; and n combo box for the invoices that associated with them. Those invoice combobox may have id = their ids in database.

1. Hide all the invoice combobox, with css : `display: none`
2. Use javascript: onchange to get the change event in the customer combobox, then show the approriate invoice combobox(`display:block`). This can be done easily by css property of Jquery, or simply manipulate by javascript replace function (to replace the html class of the combobox)

I'm sure that this way works, but the price is that you must load all data of customers & invoices, which maybe huge. So that if possible, you should try the AJAX approach like Thrustmaster & Babiker propose.